# Сделать выборку из базы данных по запросам

Tags: mysql, sql, выборка

Есть база видеороликов, у каждого из которых есть название, состоящие из нескольких слов. База на 6 млн записей.
На вход поступают поисковые запросы (также состоящие из нескольких слов).
Необходимо по этим запросам выбрать из базы наиболее релевантные записи видеороликов. Главный критерий — скорость работы.
Какие способы я пробовал:

1. Разбивал каждый поисковый запрос на массив слов и выполнял mysql запросы вида:

   ```
   select * from videos where title LIKE "%слово1%" AND title LIKE "%слово2%" AND title LIKE "%слово3%"
   ```

   Если ничего не найдено, то убирал из запроса некоторые «слова» и снова выполнял его. Работало это очень медленно.
2. Извлекал из базы все записи и проходился по ним циклом, внутри которого для каждый поисковый запрос разбивал на слова, и проверял какая доля из общего количества слов входит в название видеоролика. Если коэффициент вхождений более 0.7, то записывал этот видеоролик в результат для данного поискового запроса.
   Работает способ тоже медленно.

Прошу подсказать решение, при котором будет хорошая скорость работы (хорошей скоростью я считаю выборку 30 000 роликов за 10-20 минут на среднем ПК).

Comment: Вам стоит посмотреть поддерживает ли ваша БД полнотекстовый поиск. А вообще любой like '%xxx%' приводит к полному сканированию таблицы. Если не использовать полнотекстовые индексы, то единственный путь для каждой записи все встречающиеся слова выносить в отдельную индексную таблицу и по ней искать на полное соответствие, без like

Comment: Если по полнотекстовому поиску ничего подходящего не найдете - скажите, могу расписать велосипед с индексной таблицей подробнее

Comment: Mike, у меня знаний в этой области не очень много. Вы могли бы реализовать то, что я описал за плату? Если есть желание, пишите в скайп Thetur, договоримся

Comment: А Вы можете указать в метка, какой тип базы данных используется? MsSQL? MySQL? или что другое?

Comment: У вас БД то какая ? и вы попробовали уже в гугле вбить "название-вашей-БД полнотекстовый поиск". Не, наниматься я не буду. могу в общих чертах написать ну в принципе с основным запросом

Comment: изначально данные были в csv, я их перенес в mysql, так же могу перенести в любую другую бд, главное это скорость работы

Answer (score 1):

Можно чуть исправить Ваш первый вариант.
Делаете запрос также, как и раньше (через `LIKE`), но с двумя отличиями: 1. `WHERE` ставите через `OR`; 2. создаете свой собственный коэффициент совпадения и по нему сортируете результаты. Если `слово1` есть, то +1; если `слово2` есть, то +1 и т.д. И также можно добавить словосочетания.

```
SELECT *, (IF(title LIKE "%слово1%", 1, 0)+
    IF(title LIKE "%слово2%", 1, 0)+
    IF(title LIKE "%слово3%", 1, 0)+
    IF(title LIKE "%слово1 слово2%", 3, 0)+
    IF(title LIKE "%слово2 слово3%", 3, 0)) as relevance
FROM videos 
WHERE title LIKE "%слово1%" OR title LIKE "%слово2%" OR title LIKE "%слово3%"
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```