# Postgresql. Сортировка по релевантности полей

Tags: postgresql

Есть две таблицы, одна содержит информацию об объекте недвижимости: тип объекта, этаж, этажность, количество комнат, цена, площадь. Вторая содержит информацию о требуемом типе объекта и диапазоны поиска по этажу, этажности и т.д. Как составить запрос, который вернет отсортированный по релевантности список объектов от самого точного совпадения с диапазонами выбранной строки из второй таблицы до последнего объекта, у которого совпадает хотя бы одно поле?

`CREATE TABLE objects
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  type_id integer,--тип недвижимости
  region_id integer,--регион
  district_id integer,--район
  city_id integer,--город
  street_id integer,--улица
  building character varying(10),--строение
  price decimal (10, 2),--стоимость
  floor smallint,--этаж
  floors smallint,--этажность
  area integer,--площадь
  rooms smallint,--комнат
  CONSTRAINT objects_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)`

CREATE TABLE buy_needs
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  type_id integer,--тип недвижимости
  region_id integer,--регион
  district_id integer,--район
  city_id integer,--город
  street_id integer,--улица
  --диапозон стоимости
  price_from decimal (10, 2),
  price_to decimal (10, 2),
  --диапазон этажей
  floor_from smallint,
  floor_to smallint,
  --диапазон этажности
  floors_from smallint,
  floors_to smallint,
  --диапазон площади
  area_from integer,
  area_to integer,
  --диапазон комнат
  rooms_from smallint,
  rooms_to smallint,
  CONSTRAINT client_buy_needs_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
  Таблица objects содержит информацию об объектах недвижимости, пользователь вносит потребность в недвижимости в таблицу buy_needs(), по функционалу необходимо выбрать одну из потребностей и отобразить список подходящих объектов.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, структуру обеих таблиц с данными и примерное ожидаемое решение. Ну а насчет "виртуальной релевантности", то что-то похожее было тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490216/%D0%A1%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC/490222#490222

Comment: Если каждый параметр хранится отдельными строками, то совпадение проверяется с группировкой и для группы можно дать count() совпавших условий он и будет релеваностью. А вообще структуру данных и пример уточните

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С вашей структурой так:

```
select O.*
  from objects O join buy_needs B
    on(B.type_id=O.type_id      or O.price between B.price_from and B.price_to
    or O.region_id=B.region_id  or O.floor between B.floor_from and B.floor_to
    or O.city_id=B.city_id      or O.area  between B.area_from  and B.area_to

      ) and B.id=2 -- id поискового запроса, можно убрать что бы выполнить все поиски
 order by
    coalesce((B.type_id=O.type_id)::int,0)+
    coalesce((O.price between B.price_from and B.price_to)::int,0)+
    coalesce((O.region_id=B.region_id)::int,0)+
    coalesce((O.floor between B.floor_from and B.floor_to)::int,0)+
    coalesce((O.city_id=B.city_id)::int,0)+
    coalesce((O.area  between B.area_from  and B.area_to)::int,0) desc
```

Я не стал перечислять все колонки, добавьте недостающие по аналогии. Приведение типа `(B.type_id=O.type_id)` дает 0 если не совпало, 1 если совпало и NULL если условие NULL, coalesce приводит NULL к 0. Таким образом для order by получаем количество совпавших условий, которое и считаем релевантностью. При желании, если какие то параметры считаем более важными, умножаем получаемые значения на коэффициенты.

При большом количестве объектов в базе работать будет долго, тут без вариантов, сравнение такого количества полей, да еще с or гарантированно приведет к полному сканированию таблицы objects.

Для нормального по скорости работы варианта я бы подумал над полной переработкой структуры базы. К objects сделать дополнительную таблицу в которой для объекта держать отдельными записями каждый его параметр. Т.е. :

```
obj_id  parm_type  parm_value
  1         1         10       -- type_id
  1         2         15       -- region_id
  1         3         4        -- city_id
```

К ней можно справочник параметров, что бы parm_type в человеческие названия превращать. Поисковая таблица вся вертикальная, аналогична этой, только parm_value два from и to. На таблице по параметрам недвижимости индекс на колонки (parm_type,parm_value). В таком случае запрос при поиске будет по индексу гораздо быстрее находить нужные варианты и релевантностью будет количество совпавших записей. Т.е. можно сделать `group by id order by count(1) desc`. Правда что с вашим char полем делать в таком случае не знаю, видимо под него отдельную колонку и по ней искать на равенство или like.